# Inverting Meta attributes on jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, meta

I'm trying to invert meta attributes (content and name) by using a jQuery function but ONLY if the meta content starts with "some"

```
<meta name="abc" content="something"/>
<meta name="def" content="somewhere" />
```

I've tried this function :

```
<script>
$('meta').ready(function(){
var a_metaname = $(this).attr("name");
var a_metacontent = $(this).attr("content");

if(a_metacontent^="some") {
$('head').append("<meta name="+ a_metacontent +" content="+ a_metaname +" />");

}
 });
</script>
```

but it doesn't invert the couple name/content for each meta.

How could I improve the function ? Thanks !

Comment: @undefined isn't that bitwise XOR and assignn?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, I had forgotten that JavaScript supports that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('meta').ready(function(){
```

Here you are probably confusing two things: `$('meta').each(...)` will iterate over all meta tags. `$(document).ready(...)` waits for the ready event. `$('meta').ready(...)` will probably not do what you think.

Since the `stript` tag is, I assume, placed after the `meta` tags, you don't need to wait for the `ready` event. Not sure if you *can* modify the meta tags after the initial load (most of them take effect sooner, as far as I know). Thus, I reccomend *not* waiting.

```
$('meta').each(function(){
```

---

```
if(a_metacontent^="some") {
```

Unlike in CSS, `^=` does not mean "starts with" in Javascript. Instead, `^=` performs a bitwise XOR (after converting both operands to an integer) and assigns the result back. You can use `indexOf` for the "starts with" functionality, or you can use a regex.

```
if(/^some/.test(a_metacontent)){
```

---

```
$('head').append("<meta name="+ a_metacontent +" content="+ a_metaname +" />");
```

You keep the original meta tag in the document, as well as adding the new one. Perhaps you should remove it. Alternatively, instead of creating HTML for the browser to parse, manipulate the existing node. Parsing HTML is slow.

```
$(this).attr("content", a_metaname).attr("name", a_metacontent)
```

---

Also note that

```
$('meta').each(function(){
    if(/^some/.test($(this).attr("content"))) {
        ...
    }
}
```

can be replaced with

```
$('meta[content^="some"]').each(function(){
    ...
})
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, many thanks Jan Dvorak & @user546305

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
if (a_metacontent.match(new RegExp('some[a-z0-9A-Z]+$'))){
    $('head').append("<meta name="+ a_metacontent +" content="+ a_metaname +" />");
}
```

Comment: By the way, may I know what is it that you want to achieve doing such a thing ?

Comment: Well this is a bit complex, but basically the code is not editable for  some weeks and I have no choice to use jQuery to save some time on my project ! :)